# Parameter sent to ASP NET Core Controller from AJAX call is null if it's too large?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have AJAX code in my page which calls an ASP.NET Core controller. The code sends a list of objects to the controller. When the list is short enough, say 8 objects, the `fundFindingsGridRows` parameter is properly set to the data, however, when longer, this parameter is null.

I have tried setting several things in my Startup.cs but nothing has worked. Is there some other setting that I can configure to get this to accept larger amounts of data? Is there another issue other than size at play here?

Startup.cs (pertinent code):

```
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.MaxModelBindingCollectionSize = 100000;
        });

        services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
            options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        });

        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
        });
```

Javascript AJAX code:

```js
            var DATA = new Array();
            var grid = $("#V3FundFindingsByBuildingGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var dataTable = grid.dataSource;

            $.each(grid.items(), function (index, item) {
                var id = $(item).data('uid');
                var dataItem = dataTable.getByUid(id);
                var building = {};

                building.PANumber = dataItem.PANumber,
                building.employerNo = dataItem.employerNo,
                building.billToEntityNo = dataItem.billToEntityNo,
                building.accountNo = dataItem.AccountNo,
                building.revisionDateExists = @Model.revisionDateExists.ToString().ToLower(),
                building.settlement = false,
                building.health  = dataItem.Health,
                building.pension = dataItem.Pension,
                building.annuity = dataItem.Annuity,
                building.legal = dataItem.Legal,
                building.training = dataItem.Training,
                building.joint = dataItem.Joint,
                building.four01k  = dataItem.Four01k,
                building.healthInterest = dataItem.HealthInterest,
                building.pensionInterest = dataItem.PensionInterest,
                building.annuityInterest = dataItem.AnnuityInterest,
                building.legalInterest = dataItem.LegalInterest,
                building.trainingInterest = dataItem.TrainingInterest,
                building.jointInterest = dataItem.JointInterest,
                building.four01kInterest  = dataItem.Four01kInterest

                DATA.push(building);
            });

            var fundFindingsGridRows = JSON.stringify(DATA);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/PayrollAudit/SaveFundFindings",
                data: fundFindingsGridRows,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#FindingsByBuildingDiv').html(response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Controller Action:

```
[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]    
public IActionResult SaveFundFindings([FromBody]List<FundFindingsGridRow> fundFindingsGridRows)
        {...}
```

Data from the Header:
[image]

Parsed payload snippet:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I found away to solve this issue. What I did was to not send the data to the controller as JSON, and instead of as an array of objects. I also removed the `contentType` and `dataType` settings from the AJAX call, and changed the `data` setting:

```js
            var DATA = new Array();
            var grid = $("#V3FundFindingsByBuildingGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var dataTable = grid.dataSource;

            $.each(grid.items(), function (index, item) {
                var id = $(item).data('uid');
                var dataItem = dataTable.getByUid(id);
                var FundFindingsGridRow = {};

                FundFindingsGridRow.PANumber = dataItem.PANumber,
                FundFindingsGridRow.employerNo = dataItem.employerNo,
                FundFindingsGridRow.billToEntityNo = dataItem.billToEntityNo,
                FundFindingsGridRow.accountNo = dataItem.AccountNo,
                FundFindingsGridRow.revisionDateExists =        @Model.revisionDateExists.ToString().ToLower(),
                FundFindingsGridRow.settlement = false,
                FundFindingsGridRow.health  = dataItem.Health,
                FundFindingsGridRow.pension = dataItem.Pension,
                FundFindingsGridRow.annuity = dataItem.Annuity,
                FundFindingsGridRow.legal = dataItem.Legal,
                FundFindingsGridRow.training = dataItem.Training,
                FundFindingsGridRow.joint = dataItem.Joint,
                FundFindingsGridRow.four01k  = dataItem.Four01k,
                FundFindingsGridRow.healthInterest = dataItem.HealthInterest,
                FundFindingsGridRow.pensionInterest = dataItem.PensionInterest,
                FundFindingsGridRow.annuityInterest = dataItem.AnnuityInterest,
                FundFindingsGridRow.legalInterest = dataItem.LegalInterest,
                FundFindingsGridRow.trainingInterest = dataItem.TrainingInterest,
                FundFindingsGridRow.jointInterest = dataItem.JointInterest,
                FundFindingsGridRow.four01kInterest  = dataItem.Four01kInterest

                DATA.push(FundFindingsGridRow);
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/PayrollAudit/SaveFundFindings",
                data: { 'fundFindingsGridRows': DATA },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#FindingsByBuildingDiv').html(response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Not sure what the issue was with the JSON. If someone can let me know, I'd appreciate it in case I run across an instance where JSON is required in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo that can send the data to the controller as JSON, you can refer to it.

Student:

```
public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Name2 { get; set; }
        public string Name3 { get; set; }
        public string Name4 { get; set; }
        public string Name5 { get; set; }
        public string Name6 { get; set; }
        public string Name7 { get; set; }
        public string Name8 { get; set; }
        public string Name9 { get; set; }
        public string Name10 { get; set; }
    }
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index([FromBody] List<Student> student)
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

Index view:

```
<button onclick="postdata1()">submit(jsondata)</button>
   
@section scripts{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function postdata1() {          
            var a = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                var indexViewModel = {};
                indexViewModel.Id = i;
                indexViewModel.Name = "name" + i;
                indexViewModel.Name2 = "name2" + i;
                indexViewModel.Name3 = "name3" + i;
                indexViewModel.Name4 = "name4" + i;
                indexViewModel.Name5 = "name5" + i;
                indexViewModel.Name6 = "name6" + i;               
                indexViewModel.Name7 = "name7" + i;
                indexViewModel.Name8 = "name8" + i;
                indexViewModel.Name9 = "name9" + i;
                indexViewModel.Name10 ="name10" + i;

                a.push(indexViewModel);
            }
            var data = JSON.stringify(a);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/home/Index',
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

            }).done(function (data) {
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

result:

[image]